# GDAL/Basemap w/ Anaconda Python 2.7 w/o internet or other GIS options such as cartopy

Tags: conda, gdal, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy, osgeo

To be honest, I am overwhelmed with this.  Over the last few years, I have used Anaconda2 with both Basemap and GDAL in separate computing environments.  I am currently working with a Win10 machine that cannot be connected to the internet and I am trying to put the latest GDAL and Basemap into an Anaconda2 Python 2.7 install.

GDAL looks like it always has - you install GDAL Core, Python bindings, and set environmental settings.

Basemap is where I am a bit overwhelmed.  I read that it is nearing EOL.  So I was considering the recommendation of using the Catopy project.  However I don't have the ability to use conda, so I am a bit overwhelmed with all of the packages to make it work.  The PROJ.4 requires OSGeo4W.  The last time I installed OSGeo on a machine it broke my python installation with its own.  In addition, I don't know how to install the PROJ library through OSGeo4W w/o internet.

Could someone provide some guidance?  I may just stick with Basemap and kick the can down the road, but since I am going to the effort of updating this machine from scratch, I might as well plan for long term.

Thank you!

V/R,
Frank

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't give up on all the benefits of Conda just because you don't have an internet connection. Especially on Windows, since building packages like GDAL etc yourself is nothing but a dark art (to me at least).

I assume you do have another Windows machine with an internet connection? Since you seem to be able to transfer installation files to it.

If so, I would setup a local repository on your offline machine and add that to your Conda channels, and remove all the online channels.

You should be able to create a Conda environment on your online machine mimicking all your needs for the offline one. Make sure the platform (eg win-64) and Python version are the same. Conda will download all necessary packages, these will be in your `\pkgs\` folder inside your Conda installation. You can get the specific files if you run `conda list --explicit -n <env_name>`, that allows you to automate the copying process if necessary.

You can move these packages (just the `.tar.bz2` files) to the local repository on your offline machine, update the repository and `conda install ...` should work as normal. I do this all the time when for example traveling to locations where I cant rely on an internet connection. You could also copy the files directly to the `\pkgs\` directory on your offline machine, which should also work. But since that directory is basically just a cache, it's a little cleaner to setup the local repository. If the local repository is a shared folder other machines on the local network can also use it.

Here is some information on setting up a local repository:
[Creating custom channels](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html)

It's easier then it seems, basically creating a directory with the packages and running `conda index` on it. And you have to add the local channel to your conda setup by either modifying the `.condarc` file or running `conda config --add channels <location>`. See for details: [Managing channels](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html)